# Is there a way to extend the Spring Actuator logger and invoke it from my own controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-actuator

Is there a way to extend the Spring Actuator logger and invoke it from my own controller, so that I can do some security validations? For example, something like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyLoggingController {

    @Autowired
    private ActuatorLogger logger; // not sure what the actual class name is

    @PostMapping("/loggers")
    public String setLoggeringLevel( @RequestBody String body ) {
        
        // do security validations 
        
        // set logging level
        logger.setLoggingLevel( ... ); // not sure what the actual method signature is
        
        return response;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can secure the endpoint using Spring Security. See [Securing HTTP Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-security).

---

If Spring Security *is not an option* and you **do** want to control logging in some other way, that actuator does not provide, you can take a look at [`LoggersEndpoint`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/logging/LoggersEndpoint.java):

- To control logging level it uses [`LoggingSystem`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggingSystem.java) / [`LoggerGroups`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggerGroups.java)
- Here is a snippet of code that changes logging level:

  ```java
  @WriteOperation
  public void configureLogLevel(@Selector String name, @Nullable LogLevel configuredLevel) {
      Assert.notNull(name, "Name must not be empty");
      LoggerGroup group = this.loggerGroups.get(name);
      if (group != null && group.hasMembers()) {
          group.configureLogLevel(configuredLevel, this.loggingSystem::setLogLevel);
          return;
      }
      this.loggingSystem.setLogLevel(name, configuredLevel);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Best is to leverage the Spring Security Semantics.

Create a bean that will have a single method for checking the access for a particular Authentication Principal :

```
@Component
public class SetLoggerAccessChecker {

    public boolean isAuthorizedToChangeLogs(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // example custom logic below, implement your own
        if (request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.POST.name())) {
            return ((User) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername().equals("admin");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Inject the bean in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and use the `access` method for the specific ActuatorLoggerEndpoints :

```
    @Autowired
    private SetLoggerAccessChecker setLoggerAccessChecker;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable().requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.to(LoggersEndpoint.class)).authorizeRequests((requests) -> {
            requests.anyRequest().access("@setLoggerAccessChecker.isAuthorizedToChangeLogs(authentication, request)");
        });
    }
```

And that's it.

```
$ http -a user:password localhost:8080/actuator/loggers
// 403


$ http -a admin:password localhost:8080/actuator/loggers
// 200
```

```
$ curl --user "admin:password" -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "DEBUG"}' http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers/com.ikwattro
HTTP/1.1 204
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A013429ADE8B58239EBE385B9DEC524D; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Date: Sat, 02 Jan 2021 22:38:26 GMT
```

```
$ curl --user "user:password" -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "DEBUG"}' http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers/com.ikwattro
HTTP/1.1 403
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=2A350627672B6742F5C842D2A3BC1330; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Disposition: inline;filename=f.txt
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 02 Jan 2021 22:41:04 GMT
```

Example repository here : https://github.com/ikwattro/spring-boot-actuator-custom-security

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Denis Zavedeev, the best way to secure internal endpoints is inside of security configurer, of course if there is possibility.
For example:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/actuator/**");
}
```

Your main target is class `LoggersEndpoint`, and as @Denis Zavedeev mentioned there is method for setting log level

```
@WriteOperation
public void configureLogLevel(@Selector String name, @Nullable LogLevel configuredLevel) {
    Assert.notNull(name, "Name must not be empty");
    LoggerGroup group = this.loggerGroups.get(name);
    if (group != null && group.hasMembers()) {
        group.configureLogLevel(configuredLevel, this.loggingSystem::setLogLevel);
        return;
    }
    this.loggingSystem.setLogLevel(name, configuredLevel);
}
```

Of course you can autowire bean `LoggersEndpoint` and call proper write method, if we take a look at auto-configuration:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint(endpoint = LoggersEndpoint.class)
public class LoggersEndpointAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnBean(LoggingSystem.class)
    @Conditional(OnEnabledLoggingSystemCondition.class)
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public LoggersEndpoint loggersEndpoint(LoggingSystem loggingSystem,
            ObjectProvider<LoggerGroups> springBootLoggerGroups) {
        return new LoggersEndpoint(loggingSystem, springBootLoggerGroups.getIfAvailable(LoggerGroups::new));
    }

    static class OnEnabledLoggingSystemCondition extends SpringBootCondition {

        @Override
        public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
            ConditionMessage.Builder message = ConditionMessage.forCondition("Logging System");
            String loggingSystem = System.getProperty(LoggingSystem.SYSTEM_PROPERTY);
            if (LoggingSystem.NONE.equals(loggingSystem)) {
                return ConditionOutcome.noMatch(
                        message.because("system property " + LoggingSystem.SYSTEM_PROPERTY + " is set to none"));
            }
            return ConditionOutcome.match(message.because("enabled"));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the actual implementation [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/logging/LoggersEndpoint.java#L98).
You can change it according to your requirements. For example:

```
@Component
public class LoggingConfiguration {

    private final LoggingSystem loggingSystem;

    private final LoggerGroups loggerGroups;

    public LoggingConfiguration(LoggingSystem loggingSystem, LoggerGroups loggerGroups) {
        Assert.notNull(loggingSystem, "LoggingSystem must not be null");
        Assert.notNull(loggerGroups, "LoggerGroups must not be null");
        this.loggingSystem = loggingSystem;
        this.loggerGroups = loggerGroups;
    }

    public void configureLogLevel(String packageName, LogLevel configuredLevel) {
        Assert.notNull(packageName, "Name must not be empty");
        LoggerGroup group = loggerGroups.get(packageName);
        if (group != null && group.hasMembers()) {
            group.configureLogLevel(configuredLevel, loggingSystem::setLogLevel);
            return;
        }
        loggingSystem.setLogLevel(packageName, configuredLevel);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the LoggingConfiguration's instance however you want.

```
@RestController
public class MyLoggingController {

    @Autowired
    private LoggingConfiguration loggingConfiguration;

    @PostMapping("/loggers")
    public String setLoggeringLevel( @RequestBody String body ) {

        // do security validations

        // set logging level
        loggingConfiguration.configureLogLevel( ... );

        return response;
    }

}
```